# What is wrong with my paypal recurring code

Tags: php, paypal

I did everything right, all seem legit, but i don't see any payments made by my dummy user to the merchant:

[image]

Is it something in my code:

creating plan:

```
$req = array(
            'USER'      => 'bennyrefaelov-facilitator_api1.gmail.com',
            'PWD'  => 'YWKQ3M3NXBTZQ78U',
            'SIGNATURE' => 'AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AuVEFUpBu6N8yXkmFksuwwSiQOW8',
            'VERSION'   => '98.0',
            'METHOD'    => 'SetExpressCheckout',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => 'Mark',
            'REQCONFIRMSHIPPING'=>'0',
            'NOSHIPPING'=>'1',
            'ALLOWNOTE'=>'0',
            'SOLUTIONTYPE'=>'Sole',
            'LANDINGPAGE'=>'Billing',
            'BRANDNAME'=>'MisterSurvey',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'=>'100.00',
            'MAXAMT' => '100.00',
            'L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0' => 'Pay up',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT'=>'0',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT'=>'100.00',
            'L_BILLINGTYPE0' => 'RecurringPayments',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC'=>'An awesome package',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM'=>'This is just for fun',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'=>'USD',
            'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0'=>'itemid1',
            'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0'=>'MyItem1',
            'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0'=>'basic package',
            'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0'=>'1',
            'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0'=>'100.00',
            'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0'=>'0',
            'RETURNURL'=>'http://mistersurveylocal.com:8080/#/pricing',
            'CANCELURL'=>'http://mistersurveylocal.com:8080/#/'
       );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($req));
        $return = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

excute plan (after user agrees)

```
 $token =  Input::get('token');
     $payerId = Input::get('payerId');

$req = array(
        'USER'      => 'bennyrefaelov-facilitator_api1.gmail.com',
        'PWD'  => 'YWKQ3M3NXBTZQ78U',
        'SIGNATURE' => 'AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AuVEFUpBu6N8yXkmFksuwwSiQOW8',
        'VERSION'   => '98.0',
        'METHOD'    => 'CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile',
        'TOKEN'=>$token,
        'payerid'=>$payerId,
        'PROFILESTARTDATE' =>date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z'),
        'TOTALBILLINGCYCLES'=>'12',
        'DESC'=>'Pay up',
        'BILLINGPERIOD'=>'Month',
        'BILLINGFREQUENCY'=>'1',
        'AMT'=>'100',
        'CURRENCYCODE'=>'USD',
        'COUNTRYCODE'=>'US',
        'MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS'=>'3'
   );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($req));
    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return urldecode($return);
```

It says it's active, and verified, and the start date is at this moment, why there is no payment made?
is there something missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. As it turns out, it was an issue with the Sandbox being very slow. After 2 days of troubleshooting and debugging, all the transactions completed and I received all IPN messages related to them.

It's unfortunate, but the solution is simply to wait for them to process. Hopefully live will be much faster.